# Error when trying to use AutoCorrect module

Tags: python, python-3.x, autocorrect

My Python version is 3.5 on win32. I successfully installed the autocorrect module with

```
pip install autocorrect
```

however, when I try importing it

```
from autocorrect import spell
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-6-09b8d81ac4fb>", line 1, in <module>
runfile('C:/Users/AERizzo/Documents/Python Scripts/BagOfWords_v3.py',
    wdir='C:/Users/AERizzo/Documents/Python Scripts')

File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 685, in runfile
execfile(filename, namespace)

File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 85, in execfile
exec(compile(open(filename, 'rb').read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

File "C:/Users/AERizzo/Documents/Python Scripts/BagOfWords_v3.py", line 11, in <module>
from autocorrect import spell

File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\autocorrect\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
from autocorrect.nlp_parser import NLP_COUNTS

File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\autocorrect\nlp_parser.py", line 26, in <module>
NLP_WORDS, NLP_COUNTS = parse('big.txt')

File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\autocorrect\nlp_parser.py", line 20, in parse
words = words_from_archive(lang_sample, include_dups=True)

File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\autocorrect\utils.py", line 28, in words_from_archive
with closing(t.extractfile(tar_path)) as f:

File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\tarfile.py", line 2066, in extractfile
tarinfo = self.getmember(member)

File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\tarfile.py", line 1743, in getmember
raise KeyError("filename %r not found" % name)

KeyError: "filename 'words\\\\big.txt' not found"
```

I have looked into the utils.py and it seems to be reading from a file words.bz2. I opened the bz2 archive and the big.txt file is indeed there. What could be the issue?

Comment: The short answer is, it isn't finding the 3.5GB corpus file, but it looks like you knew that. A quick look at the code looks as if the packaging might never have been tested on Windows. A slightly longer look at the code shows that every time it is imported it parses that huge corpus file; it might get the job done, but there are certainly more efficient ways to do the task. I'd look for another package.

Comment: You are right, and indeed I decided to got around the issue by writing my own simplified version of a spell correcter. I was, however, curious to understand why it could not find that corpus file.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple errors

1. In python when you are using pip you should have an exclamation point before the pip statement.
   !pip install autocorrect
2. Spelling error
   spell should be Speller

3.Python is case sensitive:

The code should be:

!pip install autocorrect
from autocorrect import Speller

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).